# Changing LabelingFunction Color

Tags: color, labeling, text

Want to set point text label colors to match actual points. Should be obvious but...

Workaround is to change ALL label coloring but this is not desired. Would like to have black axis labels.

Also should be able to do this without combining plots with Show but I cannot determine the syntax.

```
rawfiber705 = {{145.1, 40.2}, {150, 33.4}, {148.7, 42.3}, {145, 39.9}, {142, 29.9},  {142.5, 37.9}}
rawfiber390 = {  {146.6, 35.1},  {150.9, 28.2},  {152.4, 36.8},  {146.6, 35.3},  {141.3, 25.5},  {147, 32.2}}

SetOptions[ListPlot, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True,  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick,  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Gill Sans MT", FontSize -> 14}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Bold], ImageSize -> 500];
ListPlot[(# - rawfiber705[[1]]) & /@ rawfiber705 -> {"0", "Pcw", "Pccw", "0", "Rcw", "Rccw"}, PlotStyle -> Red]

SetOptions[ListPlot, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Gill Sans MT", FontSize -> 14}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> 500];
ListPlot[(# - rawfiber390[[1]]) & /@ rawfiber390 -> {"0", "Pcw", "Pccw", "0", "Rcw", "Rccw"}, PlotStyle -> Blue]

Show[%,%%]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rawfiber705 = {{145.1, 40.2}, {150, 33.4}, {148.7, 42.3}, {145, 
    39.9}, {142, 29.9}, {142.5, 37.9}};
rawfiber390 = {{146.6, 35.1}, {150.9, 28.2}, {152.4, 36.8}, {146.6, 
    35.3}, {141.3, 25.5}, {147, 32.2}};

SetOptions[ListPlot, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Gill Sans MT", FontSize -> 14}, 
  ImageSize -> 500];

labels = {"0", "Pcw", "Pccw", "0", "Rcw", "Rccw"};

ListPlot[{
  (# - rawfiber705[[1]]) & /@ 
    rawfiber705 -> (Style[#, Red, Bold] & /@ labels),
  (# - rawfiber390[[1]]) & /@ 
    rawfiber390 -> (Style[#, Blue, Bold] & /@ labels)},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
data1 = (# - rawfiber705[[1]]) & /@ rawfiber705;
data2 = (# - rawfiber390[[1]]) & /@ rawfiber390;
styles = {Red, Blue};
labeleddata = Join@@(Thread /@ Thread[{{data1, data2}, Thread[{labels, #}] & /@ styles}]);
newdata = Callout[Style[#, #2[[2]]], Style @@ #2] & @@@ labeleddata;
options = {GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All,  PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Gill Sans MT",  FontSize -> 14}, ImageSize -> 500};

ListPlot[newdata, options]
```

[image]